# ColdFusion 10 cffile action="upload" accept attribute wildcards don't work

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This code used to work fine with ColdFusion 9:

```
<cfif form.btnSaveImage EQ "Upload">
    <cftry>
        <cffile accept="image/*" action="upload" destination="C:\T" filefield="vcImageFile" nameconflict="overwrite">
        <cfcatch type="Any">
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="cfcatch">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfif>

<form action="<cfoutput>#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#</cfoutput>" method="post" name="frmImagesAdd" id="frmImagesAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="vcImageFile">Image File*:</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="vcImageFile" id="vcImageFile" size="40" maxlength="255" message="Image file is required to upload."><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="btnSubmit" value="Add Image">
    <input name="btnSaveImage" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The issue is the `accept="image/*"` attribute of the cffile tag.  In ColdFusion 9, this wildcard used to accept any file with a MIME type that started with "image/". In ColdFusion 10, I get the following error message:

> "The MIME type or the Extension of the uploaded file image/jpeg was
>   not accepted by the server."

The MimeType value is "image/jpeg", so it should work with the wildcard.

I looked at the [wikidocs for the cffile tag](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cffile) and it says this:

> ColdFusion 10: Modifications to the attribute accept}}

However, it doesn't elaborate what those modifications are!

Looking at the [upload action docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87505342), it says that it will accept a comma delimited list of mime types.  Does this mean that wildcards are no longer accepted?

Comment: (Edit) What happens if you use [`strict=false`](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/03/coldfusion-10-cffile-restricting-file.html)? Not an answer to your question, but you might want to read this: [Secure file uploads / Don't rely on cffile accept attribute](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm). Not sure if still applies in CF 10, just FYI...

Comment: I personally have specified every image type I want to accept like this: image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, image/gif. In my opinion its better to do it this way than use a wildcard.

Comment: @volumeone - I do not know if CF10 has changed, but in earlier versions the "accept" method was easy to hack, so you should not rely on it anyway. See link above.

Comment: @Leigh, TYVM!! for the link to the info on 'don't rely on the cffile accept attribute'.  I'll have to check the code to ensure that doesn't happen!  Wish I could up-vote it more than one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, this blog post has indicated the same problem same time last year:

http://www.cutterscrossing.com/index.cfm/2013/2/21/ColdFusion-10-File-Uploads-and-MIME-Types

> Now, I remembered that there were changes to MIME type checking in CF
>   10, but I wasn't entirely sure. This code, written by one of our
>   developer's several months ago, would allow any "image" MIME type.
>   What we discovered is that we couldn't do this kind of wildcard
>   mapping under CF 10, that we now had to list out each accepted MIME
>   type as a comma delimited list.